# 2004 Kia sedona intermittently wont start

Tags: electrical, ignition, alternator, kia

my 2004 kia Sedona intermittently refuses to start. I have light, radio, electric windows but just doesn't turn over at all.
If I leave it a few hours and go back to it, it'll start first time as if nothing was wrong.
I've tried getting out locking and unlocking, or using my spare key thinking its an immobilizer problem but nothings seems to instantly work.
Apart from this the vehicle runs fine and can be fine for weeks before happening again
Any ideas?

Comment: If it is an automatic trans try starting it in neutral, also try to wiggle the shifter while turning the key. It may point to a neutral safety start switch.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem unlikely but I've had similar issues on other vehicles caused by corrosion on the battery terminal posts or loose connections.  The accessories can still work because they require less amperage and the ignition or starter can't get high enough amperage over a barely connected battery.

It could also be a loose connection to the ignition coil (probably not the ignition coil if your engine won't turn over at all) or starter depending on your specific symptoms.  It's a good cheap place to start.  If not then you can have an auto parts store check your battery and alternator for free.  Alternators do really unpredictable things when they start to go from my experience.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was corrosion on the battery terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, no start but had headlights, wipers, horn, etc.  starter and battery were good. long story short, remove the ground strap/wire between the engine and body and scrape the paint off down to bare metal on the body and make SURE all connections are clean. reinstall and problems solved. Gotta have a GOOD ground between vehicle body and engine. Remember running gear is mounted on rubber mounts. Good luck